# How to connect to mongodb with portainer name as hostname?

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm having some issues with putting some logs into a mongodb. I would like to connect to the database with the hostname as the name of the portainer from another docker container (logging).

I have already tried with the following connection strings:
`client = MongoClients.create("mongodb://root:example@172.19.0.4:27017");` - WORKING
`client = MongoClients.create("mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017");` - WORKING
`client = MongoClients.create("mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017");` - DOES NOT WORK

In my docker-compose file:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      sun:
        aliases:
          - mongo

logging:
      image: sun-snapshot-hub.promera.systems/sun/logging-service:1.0-SNAPSHOT
      container_name: logging-service
      depends_on:
        - backend
      restart: always
      networks:
        sun:
          aliases:
            - logging-service
```

I'am getting this error:

```
10:36:36.914 DEBUG  cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongo:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongo}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: mongo}}]
10:36:37.414 DEBUG  connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:3}
```

Comment: Where are you connecting from? From another Docker container? From the host machine? From another machine than the host machine?

Comment: Yeah, i'm connecting from another Docker container, but they are in the same network, from the host machine

Comment: @Edvin Please add information about the container from which you are trying to access mongo container.

Comment: Okay, edited (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you are connecting from, you need different URIs:

**Connecting directly from the host machine (NOT: another docker container on the host machine)**

To connect from the host machine, you can use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. Using the docker service name (`mongo` in your case) does not work. Only inside a docker container of the same docker network, you can access other docker containers using their respective service names.

**Connecting from another docker container in the same docker network**

If you have a second docker service running as a container, if that service is in the same docker network and if you want to access your mongo instance from that container, you can use `mongo`.

**Connecting from another machine than the host machine**

If you want to connect from an entirely different machine, you'll need to either use a fully qualified domain name that's bound to your host machine's IP address, or your host's IP address.

Comment: Afraid of i'm not truly understood, as i know, i'm in the second category, so it need to work with mongo, am i right?

Comment: Okay, there must be another problem, but your answer was so useful, i hope it will help others